# Check if my div contains a special image

Tags: jquery, detect

I would like to add a background-image to a div if this div contains an special image. I give you an example

```
<ul>
 <li><img src="image1"/></li>
 <li><img src="image2"/></li>
</ul>
```

If `img = image1`, change the background of the first li
and if `img = image2`, change the background of the second li

I know it exists somthing in jQuery :

```
$("li:has(img)")
```

But I don't know how to check if this image have the right name.

Thank you in advance !

EDIT : According to your answers, I have this

```
$("#scroller li img").each(function(){
         if ($(this).attr('src') == "theme/img/icons/moon.png"){
            $(this).parent().css("background-image", "url(../theme/img/weather-bg-rain.jpg)"); 
         }
    })
```

But my background doesn't change... :/

Comment: What do you mean by special image..? Where is the DIV anyway?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use jQuery's .each to go through each image and examine the src. If it matches what you are looking for, set your background like so:

```
$("ul li img").each(function(){
     if ($(this).attr('src') == "image1.jpg"){
           $(this).parent().css('background', '#ff0000');
     }
})
```

Comment: `this` is the `img`, so if you want to set the `li`'s background, you need to get its parent.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [`img` tag's `src` parameter in the selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/).

```
// Selects the 1st li
$("li:has(img[src='image1'])")

// Selects the 2nd li
$("li:has(img[src='image2'])")
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/T7DD2/